# How to merge two arrays from two "if" clauses together

Tags: java, arrays, merge, concatenation

I have 2 arrays that I parse from a text file:

```
if (line.startsWith("#dataOne ")){  
    String[] oneS = line.split("= ");                   
    String[]oneT= oneS[1].split(" ");
   // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oneT));            
}

if (line.startsWith("#dataFour")){
    String[] twoS = line.split("= ");   
    String[]twoSets= twoS[1].split(", ");                  
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSets));
}
```

How can I merge `oneT` and `twoSets` together?

Comment: How do you think that would work?

Comment: I don't know how this particular case would work, when they are both in separate clauses. I am aware of arraycopy, but I don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: If you had a box that fit 3 apples and another box that fit 6 apples, what size box would you need to fit 9 apples?

Comment: If i don't know how to open the box with 3 apples and the box with 6 apples, i can't fill the box that can hold 9 apples.

Comment: So review how arrays work. Review what the syntax is. Review how you can access elements and how you can iterate over them. Review how you create them and how you specify their size.

Comment: If i didn't think about it and didn't review it before asking and didn't try it by myself, and solved my problem, I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: You've shown no evidence of it. `oneT` has a length. So does `twoSets`. Create an array with a length that is the sum of those two. Iterate through each array, adding elements to it at an incrementing position in the final array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing, I think, would be to use a `List<String>` to hold the two arrays. You could do something like this:

```
List<String> merged = new ArrayList<>();
if (line.startsWith("#dataOne ")){  
    String[] oneS = line.split("= ");                
    String[]oneT= oneS[1].split(" ");
    merged.addAll(Arrays.asList(oneT));
}

if (line.startsWith("#dataFour")){
    String[] twoS = line.split("= ");   
    String[]twoSets= twoS[1].split(", ");                  
    merged.addAll(Arrays.asList(twoSets));
}
```

Then you could do things like turn it into a `String[]` if you really need an array instead of a `List`. Or you could first add the elements of `merged` to a `Set` to get rid of duplicates.

Alternatively, you would make `oneT` and `twoSets` external to the `if` blocks and merge them directly into a `String[]` using `System.arraycopy`:

```
String[] oneT;
String[] twoSets;
if (line.startsWith("#dataOne ")){  
    String[] oneS = line.split("= ");                
    oneT= oneS[1].split(" ");
} else {
    oneT = new String[0];
}

if (line.startsWith("#dataFour")){
    String[] twoS = line.split("= ");   
    twoSets= twoS[1].split(", ");                  
} else {
    twoSets = new String[0];
} 

String[] merged = new String[oneT.length + twoSets.length];
System.arraycopy(oneT, 0, merged, 0, oneT.length);
System.arraycopy(twoSets, 0, merged, oneT.length, twoSets.length);
```

Comment: I did try to make `oneT` and `twoSets` external to the if blocks, but Eclipse says that they haven't been initialized.

Comment: @user3452464 - Yeah, that's why I added an `else` clause to each `if` statement. (Note that I edited the code in the `else` clauses to fix a syntax problem; I've been doing too much JavaScript coding lately. :()

Comment: `else` helped with initialization, however it prints out the empty array. I think it is not accessing the lengths from inside the if clauses.

Comment: @user3452464 - Could you edit your question and post the current code? That would help us to see what's going on. It would also help to see some sample input.